# Difficulty with different pricing on configurable products with 2 or more configurable attributes

Tags: configurable-product, price, superattribute

I'm having a problem with pricing a configurable product (`CP`) with 2 (or more) configurable attributes (`CA`), where all of the associated simple products (`SP`) have unique prices.

When there is only one CA, the super product attribute configuration (`SPAC`) can be used to offset the prices to provide accurate pricing for each of the SP associated to this CP. However, there is a dependency introduced between the CA options when there are more than one CA and when each of the SPs has unique prices, whereas the SPAC price adjustments, whether by a fixed or percentage amount, are independent of the CA; assigned price offsets are per CA. The result is that it's impossible to use these offsets to match the ***unique*** pricing of the SPs. Note that the term *unique* is key here; some non-unique pricing of the SPs can be achieved with this method.

Has anybody worked with a problem like this? Now, it does seem that an extension that allows simple product pricing to be used could solve this problem, but I already have two product-related extensions running on this instance, so I'd like to avoid installing another one, if possible.

Right now, the only solution I can think of, besides using another extension, is to break up this product, so that it has only one CA. Any feedbacks are greatly appreciated. Thanks, and happy new year!

Comment: Sounds like you will need Simple Configurable Production Extension - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

Comment: @SubeshPokhrel. You can write that as an answer and explain a bit what the extension does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not much of an answer, but I ended up setting up the products grouped-to-simple as the parent-child. This just natively allowed simple product's prices to be selling price, and it actually worked pretty well for this particular project.